# Do iBatis annotations work when using master/salve replication with ReplicationDriver? If not, how to specify read connections?

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, replication, mybatis, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring MVC and Mybatis-Spring modules and I want to set up a Master/Slave replication, which means writing data to master and reading data from slaves.

here are my datasource settings:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql:replication://$master_ip:3306,$slave_ip:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="username" value="$user"/>
    <property name="password" value="$pwd"/>
</bean>
```

and here are my Dao file using iBatis annotations:

```
@Repository 
public interface UserMapper {
    @Select("select * from user")
    public List<User> getUsers(long id);
    @Insert("insert into user (name, age) values (#{name},#{age})")
    public List<User> getUsers(long id);
//..other methods
}
```

And I think that according to the @Select and @Insert annotations, Mybatis will know whether it's a 'read-only' connection or not, thus reading from the slave db or inserting into the master db.

However, things went wrong. It turned out that no matter what kind of method that is executing, only master can receive the query.

I read the general_log file of the slave db and find that there really are connections to it but no queries(and surely dump history are recorded in the relay-log). On the contrary there are both select and insert queries in the  general_log file of master db.

Theses are part of the general_log file of the slave db:

```
    378298 Connect  root@10.1.168.133 on test
    378298 Query    /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.34 ( Revision: jess.balint@oracle.com-20141014163213-wqbwpf1ok2kvo1om ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'license' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
    378298 Query    /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.34 ( Revision: jess.balint@oracle.com-20141014163213-wqbwpf1ok2kvo1om ) */SELECT @@session.auto_increment_increment
    378298 Query    SET NAMES utf8
    378298 Query    SET character_set_results = NULL
    378298 Query    SET sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
    378298 Query    set session transaction read only
    378298 Quit
```

Theses are part of the general_log file of the master db:

```
       87 Connect root@10.10.72.204 on test
       87 Query /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.19 ( Revision: tonci.grgin@oracle.com-20111003110438-qfydx066wsbydkbw ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
       87 Query /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.19 ( Revision: tonci.grgin@oracle.com-20111003110438-qfydx066wsbydkbw ) */SELECT @@session.auto_increment_increment
       87 Query SHOW COLLATION
       87 Query SHOW CHARACTER SET
       87 Query SELECT @@session.autocommit
       87 Query SET NAMES utf8mb4
       87 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
       87 Query SET autocommit=1
       87 Query SET sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
       87 Query SET autocommit=0
       87 Query SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
       87 Query select `internal_unique_id`, `threshold`, `mail_list`, `status` from `threshold_alarm`
       87 Query commit
```

So my question is: Do iBatis annotations work when using master/salve replication with ReplicationDriver? If not, how to specify read connections?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a general practice in enterprise applications, 2 diffrent datasources are used to achieve this. 1 for writes and other for reads with their corresponding transaction isolation level. So explicitly inject the needed datasource when creating the template.

Comment: @Vishnu thanks for your suggestion! The reason I assume that Mybatis will do this is that when I previously use only jdbc with no database framework, I can simply use one datasource and specify `conn = dataSource.getConnection(); conn.setReadOnly(true)`, then I get a read-only connection....

Comment: yes thats just a hint to the underlying DB driver to perform optimization, but do search your code there will be a call where the readonly is set to false before issuing an insert statement. So the right answere to your question is my answere in the first comment.

Comment: @Vishnu I see..Then could you please tell me how to "explicitly inject the needed datasource when creating the template?" I tried to figure it out but failed..Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Basically create 2 datasource in your configuration file, and inject the needed datasource based on your requirement.

Sample Code:

```
 <bean id="readonlyDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://${db.host}:5432/${db.name}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    <property name="defaultReadOnly" value="true"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://${db.host}:5432/${db.name}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="readOnlyJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="readOnlydataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and then in your dao layer use the correct jdbc template.
Again if your not comfortable with 2 datasources, you can explicitly get the connection object from jdbctemplate and the set connection readonly to true.

Evaluate your performance considertaions.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually there are no `JdbcTemplate` in my project. I use Mybatis-Spring so my Dao files are like `XXXMapper` with`@Repository` annotation which is of the class `org.springframework.stereotype.Repository`. So I'm afraid your method doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Ok not an issue then just use the datasouce beans to inject where the connection object is initialized, specifically the SqlSessionFactory bean.

Comment: I did some research and find this[Best approach for Spring+MyBatis with Multiple Databases to support failovers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201075/mybatis-spring-multiple-databases-java-configuration), but configuring 2 datasource means I have to keep two version of `XXXMapper` files for reading and writing which is a bad idea...And I also found that maybe Spring's `AbstractRoutingDataSource.` can be a solution and I'll work on that later. Thanks!