# Spring 4, MyBatis, multiple data sources with annotations

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, spring-annotations

I am currently in a Spring 4 application that uses MyBatis and is completely annotation-driven (that cannot change per architecture requirements).  I am trying to add a second data source definition with a completely separate set of mapping configurations.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the two data sources to play nicely together.

I created a new, virtually identical class and added `@Qualifier` data to the new file.

The configuration for the classes looks like this:

**Data Source 1**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan (basePackages = "com.myproject.package1", annotationClass = Mapper.class)
public class DataSource1 {

  @Bean
  @Qualifier ("DS1")
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    /* configuration loaded */
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier ("DS1")
  public SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    /* mapper resources added */
    return bean.getObject();
  }
}
```

**Data Source 2**

```
@Configuration
@MapperScan (basePackages = "com.myproject.package2", annotationClass = Mapper.class)
public class DataSource2 {

  @Bean
  @Qualifier ("DS2")
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    /* configuration loaded */
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier ("DS2")
  public SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    bean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    /* mapper resources added */
    return bean.getObject();
  }
}
```

When this runs I get exception messages like:

> org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found)

If I comment-out the data in DS2, DS1 works just fine again.  I tried adding the mapper scanning configuration data in another bean and setting the name of the `SqlSessionFactoryBean` to pass into it but that did not work.

Suggestions?

## UPDATE

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201075/mybatis-spring-multiple-databases-java-configuration) and updated to use the following.

```
@Bean (name = "the_factory_1")
public SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() { /* same code */ }

@Bean
public MapperScannerConfigurer getMapperScannerConfigurer() {
  MapperScannerConfigurer configurer = new MapperScannerConfigurer();
  configurer.setBasePackage("com.myproject.package1");
  configurer.setAnnotationClass(Mapper.class);
  configurer.setSqlSessionFactoryBeanName("the_factory_1");
  return configurer;
}
```

However, that leads me to this error:

> No qualifying bean of type [com.myproject.package1.mapper.MyMapper] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

When I debug only one `@Bean` for the factory gets invoked.

## UPDATE 2

If I move everything to a single file all is fine.  However, that is not ideal as I want the `DataSource` definitions to be separated.  That's my only hurdle right now.

Comment: I looked at this and am not sure what I doing wrong:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201075/mybatis-spring-multiple-databases-java-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use DAOFactory pattern to get connections for multiple datasources like DS1 and DS2 and use DAOUtil class to provide required configuration using annotation

Comment: I currently don't have the option to change the way the first data source is set up.  It's one of those "code will be rejected if you don't follow what is already there" scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ace-mybatis](https://github.com/vendigo/ace-mybatis), it simplifies configuration.

Add one bean.

```
@Bean
public static AceMapperScannerConfigurer mapperScannerConfigurer() {
    return AceMapperScannerConfigurer.builder()
            .basePackage("com.myproject.package1")
            .build();
}
```

And then mark your mapper interfaces with @AceMapper and specify sqlSessionFactory

```
@AceMapper(sqlSessionFactoryBeanName = "firstSqlSessionFactory")
public interface UserMapper {
 Stream<User> selectUsers();
}

@AceMapper(sqlSessionFactoryBeanName = "secondSqlSessionFactory")
public interface ClientMapper {
 Stream<Client> selectClients();
}
```